# Compile multiple modules in Android Gradle Dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, andengine

I'm trying to create an app with andEngine WITH its physicsBox2D extension. For that, I have to add 2 modules and then compile in my app - `andEngine` and `andEngine PhysicsBox2D`. I have the following Gradle code -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.sample.practice"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2D')
    compile project(':andEngine')
}
```

But this code gives this error while running - `...java.exe finished with non zero exit value 2`

If I remove `compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2D')` from Gradle, the app runs fine.
But this code is important for the app to work. Any ideas how I can implement both `andEngine` and `andEngine PhysicsBox2D` in the dependencies of Gradle?

Thanx

**PS -** I'm using experimental Android Gradle Plugin V.0.2 with Android Studio 1.3 for some NDK stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box2d extension needs AndEngine module as its dependency and your project also needs both of them as its dependencies. Also It should be noted that order of dependencies *matters* as well.

So you should make sure you have three gradle files configured like below.

- **Your game gradle file:**

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile project(':andEngine')
      compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2D')
  }
  ```
- **AndEngine gradle file:**

  It does not have any dependency.
- **Box2d Extension gradle file:**

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile project(':andEngine')
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by this -

1) There were some problems in andEngine, solved those errors.

2) Enabled `multiDex` in `Gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2
The following script is working fine with me.

### See if this can help?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxxx.yyy'
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/gfx/'] } }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile project(':andengine')
    compile project(':andenginebox2dextension')
}
```